# Double integral for exponential function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to find the cdf of this function $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$.

My attempt:
$$F(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_u^x e^{-v}dvdu$$

Am I on the right path? Can someone help me with how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in one of the upper limits (there should be a dependency on $y$ somewhere). If $y < x$, we can project the point $(x, y)$ onto the boundary of the sector $0 < x < y$:
$$\operatorname P(X < x, Y < y) =
\int_0^{\min(x, y)} \int_u^y e^{-v} dv du \,[x > 0 \land y > 0] = \\
(1 - e^{-\min(x, y)} - \min(x, y) e^{-y}) \,[x > 0 \land y > 0].$$

[image]